# Difference between adding and omitting template parameter for class name inside constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, typename, injected-class-name

I want to know if there is essentially a difference between:

```
template <typename T> 
class foo{
  foo<T>(){};
};

template<typename T>
class foo{
  foo(){};
};
```

Both seem to work, but I don't understand the difference between the two. The first one is confusing me, I don't understand what's the role of the < T > here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the rule of [injected-class-name](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#2), they're exalctly the same thing.

[$14.6.1/1 Locally declared names [temp.local]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local#1):

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an
>   injected-class-name (Clause [class]). The injected-class-name can be
>   used as a template-name or a type-name. When it is used with a
>   template-argument-list, as a template-argument for a template
>   template-parameter, or as the final identifier in the
>   elaborated-type-specifier of a friend class template declaration, it
>   refers to the class template itself. Otherwise, it is equivalent to
>   the template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class
>   template enclosed in <>.

So `foo` and `foo<T>` refer to the same thing here. More specifically,

> The first one is confusing me, I don't understand what's the role of the < T > here.

You're using the inject-class-name `foo` with its template parameter `T` (i.e. `foo<T>`), which refers to the template class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since C++20, the longer form is no longer valid and you have to use the shorter form that relies on *injected-class-name*.

See [[diff.cpp17]#class-2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/diff.cpp17#class-2):

> a simple-template-id is no longer valid as the declarator-id of a constructor or destructor

With the following example in the spec:

```
template<class T>
struct A {
  A<T>();           // error: simple-template-id not allowed for constructor
  A(int);           // OK, injected-class-name used
  ~A<T>();          // error: simple-template-id not allowed for destructor
};
```

And indeed GCC trunk version [rejects code using the longer form](https://godbolt.org/z/3eT7ze) (while Clang 11 and GCC 10.2 [still accepts it](https://godbolt.org/z/adG8sK)).